# How to back up an app which is no longer on store?

Tags: apps, store, nokia-lumia-535, backup, reset

Calc Pro, a basic MATLAB programming app, I had installed on my phone a couple of months ago. Now it is not available in store as I receive error message code 1 when I tap on the app in **My Library** in store.Now I want to reset my phone and don't want to lose the app. Is there any way I can back up the app somewhere and retrieve it from overthere later on? I am running 14393.479 on Lumia 535. The app is no more on the store nor I have any xap of it.